# How did GLaDOS open portals in the beginning?

Tags: video-games, portal

If you look at the beginning of the original *Portal* game, GLaDOS opened portals for us.

While the portals were opened on plain white surfaces, **how could GLaDOS do it without portal gun?** Portals weren’t some in-built capability of walls that GLaDOS could manipulate using code and that’s why she needed us to further her agenda (only a human could use portal gun due to its design).

Comment: The portal gun can be used by GLaDOS when it's mounted on its pedestal, or by either of her testing robots (ATLAS and P-Body). No humans required.

Comment: @Valorum Which pedestal mounting are you talking about? I don’t remember any instance. Also, are ATLAS and P-Body part of main story? I thought they were created for multiplayer mode.

Comment: @Valorum The mounting from where we pick the portal gun can’t move. So, that’s useless.

Comment: She can move anything in any of the chambers to any position.

Comment: @Valorum No, she can’t.

Comment: Of course she can..we see her restructuring walls, floors and ceilings throughout the game.

Comment: @Valorum They were as per testing room specifications. We see background of the rooms in both Portal and Portal 2 games. There were hydraulics and cube-transporting tubes. The rooms weren’t made of nanotech.

Comment: She can (and does) move the walls to push things, then move them back. No nanotech required for _moving_ things.

Comment: @SatelliteofSin In the video you linked in your question, you can see the pedestal from which you grab the gun rotating and using the gun automatically before it is retrieved by the player. See starting at [2:35](https://youtu.be/0P2dzIa6pZY?t=155), for example.

Comment: @reirab Interestingly, the walls it's shooting have the "autoportal" bars shown in Valorum's answer, which implies they wouldn't need shooting at all.

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, I noticed that, too. It's probably only actually programmed to really shoot portals when the player is using it and then just scripted to rotate and emit a particle for those couple of scenes, then use the script to trigger the autoportal at the time that the emitted particle would collide with the wall (either through actual collision detection or just a hard-coded time based on the known distance traveled and speed of the particle.) Probably just saved some programming time that way rather adding an actual special case for how the gun works.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 As I already said, they were as per testing room specifications. Yes, she could use some hydraulics beyond the testing guidelines, but that’s it.

Comment: @reirab From what little I remember of my Hammer days, the "autoportal" is just a pretty shape, and the portal gun is the thing actually creating the portals; there's code for the pedestal-shooting version. (Though there is also a command to create a portal at a certain location, so I'm pretty sure both approaches were used in the actual game. The very first portal is not created by a portal gun.)

Comment: P-Body appears very briefly in the main game in Portal 2; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKfxjW09c2Q and is therefore part of the official continuity

Comment: @Valorum LOL. I can’t believe this. 

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is an [*Autoportal*](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Portal_Spawner), also described as a '*Portal Spawner*' in the official game level creator.

[image]

The mechanic isn't described, but the Autoportal has two bars on either side that appear to emit one side of a portal, either blue or orange in a testing area.

[image]

Comment: Note that the *Portal 2* model looks [significantly more obvious](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Portal_Spawner#/media/File:Portal2spawner.png), and we can clearly see that it is actively projecting the portal (the lights along either side match the portal's color, point towards the portal, and turn off when the portal is removed). I like this model a lot more than the *Portal* model, which looks a bit arbitrary in its design.